# How to get RE for this DFA Using Arden's Theorem? Unable to get desired Regular expression

Tags: regex, automata, finite-automata, dfa

Desired RE: `0*10*1(1+00*1)*` Vs RE I got `0*1(0 + 11* 0)*11*`

```
    q0 = q0 0 + ε           equ (1)
    q1 = q0 1 + q1 0 + q2 0     equ (2)
    q2 = q1 1 + q2 1            equ (3)
    
    q0 = ε + q0 0           R=Q+RP
    q0 = ε 0*           R=QP*
    q0 = 0*             εR*=R*
    
    q2 = q1 1 + q2 1
    q2 = q1 11*         equ (4)
    
    Substitute the value of q2 in equ (2)
    q1 = q0 1 + q1 0 + q2 0
    q1 = 0*1 + q1 0 + q1 11* 0
    q1 = 0*1 + q1 (0 + 11* 0)       R=Q+RP
    q1 = 0*1((0 + 11* 0)*)*     R=QP*
    q1 = 0*1(0 + 11* 0)*        (R*)*=R*
    
    Substitute the value of q1 in equ (4)
    q2 = q1 11*
    q2 = 0*1(0 + 11* 0)*11*
```

I've tried to solve the DFA to get the Desired RE but unable to achieve what I'm looking for.

Here is DFA for which I'm trying to get the RE:
[image: DFA]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: do you want a different DFA to match the desired RE, or do want a different proof to show that/if that DFA matches the desired RE?

Comment: Second question, is `q0` your only start state? I'm not sure what semantics your yellow highlighting is supposed to have.

Comment: Actually, your two REs are both correct as far as I can tell, if `q0` is the only start state.

Comment: Wow, I've been working on this for a while now. It's obvious the desired RE is correct when you just follow along to DFA, but I can't see how to prove it using Arden's Theorem.

Comment: @joanis Yes q0 is the only start state. I just want to match both the REs, when you follow along with DFA and when you're going with Arden's Theorem.

Comment: Does the theorem work backward too, with `R = Q + PR` implying `R = P*Q`? That might be a way to get the second `0*` in the desired RE.

Comment: As far as I know, we are not allowed to do that. And also tell me that the RE I got using Arden's Method is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, your RE is correct too. I'm just stumped as to how to prove the desired one. I've been working on it for the last half hour but still haven't found.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Really appreciated. If you prove it somehow, please let me know.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the DFA into the equivalent DFA with q1 split into q1' with the transition from q0, and q1'' with the transition from q2? I think the desired RE would come out fairly easily from that equivalent DFA.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you found is correct, and comes out naturally from the structure of the DFA as your show it, but to get the Desired RE you specified, you need to transform the DFA into this equivalent DFA:

[image]

This DFA is equivalent to yours: I have split `q1` into two states, `q1` and `q1'`, the `q1` receiving the transition from `q0` and `q1'` receiving the transition from `q2`, both having the same transitions out. (This is not a formal proof of equivalence, I know, but it's the underlying intuition for such a proof.)

With this DFA, the proof is quite straightforward:

```
q0 = q0 0 + ε
   = ε0*
   = 0*
q1 = q0 1 + q1 0
   = 0*1 + q1 0
   = 0*10*    
q1'= q2 0 + q1' 0
   = q2 00*
q2 = q1 1 + q2 1 + q1' 1
   = 0*10*1 + q2 1 + q2 00*1
   = 0*10*1 + q2 (1 + 00*1)
   = 0*10*1 (1 + 00*1)*
```

Answer (score 0):

From the given DFA, the equations for each state can be written as:

```
q0=q0.0+ε
q1=q1.0+q0.1+q2.0
q2=q2.1+q1.1
```

Now q0 is in the form t=tr+s so the solution is t=sr* (Arden's Theorem)

```
q0=ε.0*
q0=0*
```

Substitute q0 in q1,

```
q1=q1.0+0*1+q2.0
```

Now q1 is in the form t=tr+s so the solution is t=sr*

```
q1=(0*1+q2.0)+q1.0 (t=s+tr is t=sr*)
q1=(0*1+q2.0)0*
q1=0*10*+q2.00*
```

Substitute q1 in q2,

```
q2=q2.1+(0*10*+q2.00*)1
q2=q2.1+0*10*1+q2.00*1
```

Now q2 is in the form t=tr+s so the solution is t=sr*

```
q2=q2(1+00*1)+0*10*1 (t=s+tr is t=sr*)
q2=0*10*1(1+00*1)*
```

Since q2 is the final state, the Regular expression will be:

```
RE=0*10*1(1+00*1)*
```